# Does dying count as tripping?

Tags: temple-run-2

In **Objectives** that need you to go a certain distance without tripping (in my case 5,000 metres), does dying and then being resurrected (through **gems**) count as tripping?

I say this because I **resurrected** and completed 5,000 metres, to my knowledge, *without tripping*, but did not get the +1 Multiplier.

Comment: I believe, dying counts as tripping.

Comment: I believe I have had a different experience.  At least for completing the 5000 meter objective, I'm 90% sure I succeeded in completing it on a run where I died an rezzed before 5000 m.  I will try to confirm in subsequent runs.

Comment: Please confirm and answer! :)

Comment: I have now confirmed (my answer below) with the current version of the game. You can save yourself and still complete the challenge for both the 2500 and 5000 m objectives. Have you been able to complete it?

Comment: Haven't really played much, exams are coming!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dying **does not** count as tripping. You can complete the "no tripping" objectives by using Save Mes. You can also use a headstart.

Comment: But I'm a 100% sure I did not trip for 5,000 metres.